# How to run a ruby program without specifying the path

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I have built my program and installed the gem using

```
$sudo gem install ./helloworld-0.0.1.gem
```

Now I need to have a command named `helloworld` so I can run the program from anywhere in the file system. I need something which can produce the following output.

```
$helloworld
 hello world
```

The gemspec file is as follows.

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name               = "helloworld"
  s.version            = "0.0.1"
  s.default_executable = "helloworld"

  s.required_rubygems_version = Gem::Requirement.new(">= 0") if s.respond_to? :required_rubygems_version=
  s.authors = ["Suranga"]
  s.date = %q{2015-08-06}
  s.description = %q{Hello World}
  s.files = ["Rakefile", "lib/helloworld.rb"]
  s.test_files = ["test/test_helloworld.rb"]
  s.require_paths = ["lib"]
  s.rubygems_version = %q{1.6.2}
  s.summary = %q{Hello World!}

  if s.respond_to? :specification_version then
    s.specification_version = 3

    if Gem::Version.new(Gem::VERSION) >= Gem::Version.new('1.2.0') then
    else
    end
  else
  end
end
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you specify a bin file in your gemspec?  Show your `gemspec` file to help us better answer your question. [This may be enough of a hint for you though.](http://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/2vz7hi/creating_an_executable_gem/)

Comment: Please have a look at my gemspec file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`default_executable` setting is deprecated](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/v2.4.8/lib/rubygems/specification.rb#L679) and doesn’t specify an executable anyway. You need to use [`executables`](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#executables) instead:

```
s.executables << "helloworld"
```

Also have a look at the [adding an executable](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable) section of the Rubygems guide.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a default setup.

### Use rvm

First, I suggest you to install `rvm` (http://rvm.io). Then you wont need sudo permissions and can install gems in sane (testing, development) environments.

### Use a tool to prepare your gem-work

Second, if you plan to implement a gem, I suggest you use `bundler` (and there are many probably superb alternatives) to give you a basic structure. If called like

```
bundle gem --bin helloworld
```

It will create the sketch of a helloworld gem for you, with a file in the directory `exe` that will be placed on your `$PATH` when installed - so that you can call it
(see `bundle help gem` for a few more options). I dislike the new directory name (`exe/` used to be `bin/`), but what bundler produces is still a very good and lean outline, I find.

During development you will find yourself playing around with it like this (then it will not use any "installed" version of the gem)

```
bundle exec exec/helloworld
```

Happy coding!